# Execute Thread on another process, but allow the action to return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have an MVC application that needs to fire a process, lets call it UpdateTheIndex.  The action that fires this off needs to go ahead and return and then the user will have javascript that updates the page with the status.  I implemented a BackgroundWorker, but this does not allow my thread to return.  What else can I use that will allow the MVC action to complete while the worker finishes up?  The UpdateTheIndex can take from 2 to 30 min, and I want the user to watch on the webpage, so the action has to return after it starts the process.

```
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(IndexWorker);
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(INDEX_DIR);
```

Comment: I should say that I can think of tons of ways to skin this cat, but really the way I have stated it is how it needs to be solved.  I could do a WCF service, a windows service, javascript calls to no mans land, and many other options.  In the end I need this to fire in-process, but be able to return the action result.  Perhaps it cant be done, and thats ok, but thats what I need to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app pool isn't really the place to be doing such long running tasks at there is always a risk it will be recycled from under your feet. I would suggest taking this task out-of-process and signalling to it when to do work (WPF?). If really want to proceed look into the [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) for Asp.Net MVC2

Comment: I do understand you point about the worker being recycled, I didnt really give that much thought.  A worker cant really recycle unless all threads have died, so perhaps I need to just create an action and call it via javascript with the intention that it wont return until its finished.  I did think about a service or WPF app, the problem is I want this on a commercially hostable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write standalone service, that would do the job.

*Page <--> WebServer <--> IndexService*

Scenario is as follows:
Browser sends request to WebServer to start the work, then WebService triggers IndexService and MVC Action ends. Afterwards Browser polls WebServer for status of operation. And WebServer proxies request to IndexService.
WebServer can communicate IndexService by for example Wcf.

Comment: A service would work, but takes me out of the app and puts me into another app (or service in the app) and adds more complexity.  I also dont get access to the Cache for which I want to store the index status.  In this app, there is no writable database, so storing the progress is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the nature of BackgroundWorker, but 2 alternatives you could use instead:

Thread pool

```
// This passes the delegate to the thread pool and works in parallel
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (delegate {...});
```

The only caveat with thread pool is that you have figure out a way to determine when the action completed (you could set up events to fire at the end of the action). The newer .NET 4.0 library uses parallel tasks to work with determining completion.

Task parallel library (.NET 4.0)

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew (delegate {...});
// Do other work
BusyWork();
// Check if done
if (task.IsCompleted) ...
// To wait on task to complete:
task.Wait();
```

Comment: I thought of a thread pool, and have used them in the past.  I will try it in the morning as I am about to go home.  As long as the thread pool will let the calling thread die, or at least complete so I can get my actionresult back I am fine with it.